# Emoji translator from :shortname: to CodePoint in Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, emoji

Does anyone knows some plugin which works well with WebPack for translating emojis from :shortcode: to CodePoints ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/emojione plugin works good with webpack and you have many features here